# How to get post or page excerpt using post_excerpt

Tags: pages, excerpt, php

I am using the following `foreach` loop:

```
$pages = get_pages(array ('post_type' => 'page','sort_column' => 'menu_order',));
   foreach ($pages as $page) {
     $apage = $page->post_name;
     if ( $apage =='about') { 
            echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content)
        } // if about page
   } // foreach
```

I would like to be able to get the excerpt of the page or post instead of the whole content by using

```
 $post->post_excerpt
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Seems that I some how misunderstood you. I do think you are missing the point of the `post_excerpt`.

When you create a new post or page (AFAIK for pages as well), you have the opportunity to create a manual excerpt in the excerpt meta box (to make it available, just enable it in screen options dropdown when in the add new/edit post/page screen). This manual excerpt (or **user defined excerpt**) that you enter in that meta box is saved under `post_excerpt`, which you can then retrieve with `$post->post_excerpt`. If that meta box is empty, ie, if you haven't specified a manual excerpt, nothing will be returned

It does not work the same as the template tag, `the_excerpt()` that creates an excerpt on the fly by using the content to create an excerpt, which BTW doesn't work on pages.

Please check out [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

> post_excerpt
>
> string
>
> User-defined post excerpt

**EDIT 2**

If the manual excerpt meta box is not displayed, you can simply activate it with the following code

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Your usage of `get_pages` here is wrong here. `get_pages` is not intended for this use.

You should be using a custom query with either [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

You can do something like this to display your pages and excerpts

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=page' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
       the_title();
       the_excerpt();
    }
  } else {
  // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into functions.php, it will add support for excerpts in Pages

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
    function my_custom_init() {
        add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
    }
?>
```

Use this to show up the excerpt..

```
 $pages = get_pages(array ('post_type' => 'page','sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
   foreach ($pages as $page) {
     $apage = $page->post_name;
     if ( $apage =='about') { 
            echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', $page->post_content);
        } // if about page
   } // foreach
```

Comment: Thanks. I though about that, but I was more not so interested to see the excerpt option in the admin area that I did not think it could be my problem. Again, thanks. :)

Comment: Spoke too soon. didn't work

Comment: try
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=about' ); 

// The Loop
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I ended up using the above code. I will have to go with multiple queries instead of foreach loop. I really still want to know how to get excerpt using the foreach loop I submitted.